# New levels not available?

Tags: star-wars-tiny-death-star

New levels are showing ready to build. But when I try to build them, I get told there are none available. I'm using iOS version. Anyone else having this issue. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep trying.  I was able to get several of them about an hour ago on Windows Phone.

Answer (score 1):

While there are new levels to build, (One Residential, one Recreational, and 2 Imperial) there are others which are still locked.

I guess we just wait.

I'm on Android.

Note if you choose the option to "Choose specific level", it will show you all the unlocked levels available

Comment: Thanks. I didn't even pay attention to the lock.